# Streamlit : plot a streamlit bar chart of a data frame value counts

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, streamlit

How to display a (streamlit) bar chart of `df['column_name'].value_counts()` ?

Answer (score 3):

Using **Seaborn** & **st.pyplot**

```
import seaborn as sns
import streamlit as st
```

```
val_count  = df['column_name'].value_counts()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(val_count.index, val_count.values, alpha=0.8)
fig.title('Some title')
fig.ylabel('y label', fontsize=12)
fig.xlabel('x label', fontsize=12)


# Add figure in streamlit app
st.pyplot(fig)
```

or

Convert pandas `value_counts` output to `dataframe`

```
df1 = df['column_name'].value_counts().rename_axis('unique_values').reset_index(name='counts')
```

Using [st.bar_chart](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.bar_chart)

```
st.bar_chart(df1)
```